# GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_BINDING when block is not bound to index

Tags: opengl, uniform

What will be returned by `glGetActiveUniformBlock` with `GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_BINDING`, if specified uniform block was not bound to any binding index? http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glGetActiveUniformBlock.xml says:

> If no uniform block has been previously specified, zero is returned.

Does it mean that zero will be returned for unbound block? If yes, does it mean that after program linkage all unifrom blocks are bound to zero bining index by default? Again, if yes, then how can I tell if specified block is bound to zero or it was never bound to any index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your first two question, yes.

> Again, if yes, then how can I tell if specified block is bound to zero or it was never bound to any index?

You don't. Then again, what purpose would that serve? You should either be setting these from your code or from the shader. In both cases, you know what was set because you set it. Unless you're writing some shader tool that asks the user to specify a binding, then it shouldn't matter.

And if you are writing such a tool, then simply show the user what all of the bindings are. If multiple uniform blocks use the same index, then it's illegal for the user to proceed until they resolve the conflict (or confirm that it's what they really want).

Comment: Of course I know what was set, but I request `GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_BINDING` in different parts of code. So special error state of such request could help to detect erroneous calls and make testing a bit easier.

Comment: @Sergey: That suggests some confusion in the code. Personally, I would suggest building a simple convention for this sort of stuff. One kind of block always uses index 0 (for example, the projection matrix which is shared among all rendering shaders). Index 1 goes to something else (say, the model-to-view transforms). Index 2 may be where lighting parameters go. And so forth. Or, to put it another way, set things up so that you don't [i]have[/i] to ask. The way I see it, just about any time you're using `glGet*`, you're probably doing something wrong.